# Using LINQ queries vs Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

In our new project we are hoping to use entity framework 4.0. I would like to know what would be the best method from below options for accessing the database when using entity framework. development wise, maintenance wise and performance wise.

1. Use LINQ queries
2. Use Stored Procedures

Comment: So many times this question asked in SOF. Before posting this question, you should be guided by Ask Question UI itself. Don't try posting duplicate question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use stored procedure for transacting data. It gives the max performance in transactions. Using LINQ with entity FW should degrade the performance.

Comment: You say this without having proof or references to performance tests. Bit ridiculous! It should not really matter, especially not when you executed stored procedures and then map everything to entities. Besides that, I so often see people place "IF" statements in stored procedures. Every different outcome to an if means throwing away the execution plan and creating a new one. In LINQ this isn't possible, so a big bonus. Lots of other benefits of sprocs are also myths.